# [Big help]Custom transition animation not triggered when VC present

Tags: ios, swift, animation, transition, presentviewcontroller

:)

I want make some change to source code for 17-custom-presentation-controller to make custom transition animation,all my change is in class PopAnimator.

all my code is in here : https://github.com/hopy11/TransitionTest

This is my changes:

add a new instance variable in PopAnimator to save transitionContext:

var ctx:UIViewControllerContextTransitioning!

I rewrite the method:

animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning)

to this :

```
func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
    let containerView = transitionContext.containerView
    let toView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .to)!

    //save transitionContext
    ctx = transitionContext

    containerView.addSubview(toView)

    let animation = CATransition()
    animation.duration = duration / 2

    animation.type = "cube"
    //use type kCATransitionReveal is not work too ...
    //animation.type = kCATransitionReveal

    animation.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft
    animation.delegate = self

    containerView.layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
}
```

3.Last I make class PopAnimator confirm CAAnimationDelegate delegate, and add the new method:

```
func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
    if ctx != nil{
        //make transition complete
        ctx.completeTransition(true)
        dismissCompletion?()
    }
}
```

When run the App,the transition animation is look good when detailsVC dismiss,but nothing happened when presenting detailsVC!

[image: demo]

You can see the demo above : when user tap the bottom left green view,it present detailsVC,but no animation happened!!! but when dismiss detailsVC,the animation work fine!

What’s wrong with it???
and how to fix it???

all my code is in here : https://github.com/hopy11/TransitionTest

thanks a lot! :)